# How to auto click button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code which takes the address information from Google mab
Is there a way to make the Google mab automatically load whenever I enter the Address page instead of clicking the icon to load it?

```
setAddress() {
return Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .subtitle2
            .copyWith(color: colors.fontColor),
        focusNode: addFocus,
        controller: addressC,
        validator: (val) =>
            validateField(val, getTranslated(context, 'FIELD_REQUIRED')),
        onSaved: (String value) {
          address = value;
        },
        onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
          _fieldFocusChange(context, addFocus, locationFocus);
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: getTranslated(context, 'ADDRESS_LBL'),
          isDense: true,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 5),
      width: 40,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(
          Icons.my_location,
          size: 20,
        ),
        focusNode: locationFocus,
        onPressed: () async {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

          await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Map(
                        latitude: latitude == null
                            ? position.latitude
                            : double.parse(latitude),
                        longitude: longitude == null
                            ? position.longitude
                            : double.parse(longitude),
                        from: getTranslated(context, 'ADDADDRESS'),
                      )));
          if (mounted) setState(() {});
          List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              double.parse(latitude), double.parse(longitude));

          state = placemark[0].administrativeArea;
          country = placemark[0].country;
          pincode = placemark[0].postalCode;
          //  address = placemark[0].name;
          if (mounted)
            setState(() {
              countryC.text = country;
              stateC.text = state;
              pincodeC.text = pincode;
              // addressC.text = address;
            });
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F34B.png

Is there a way to make the Google mab automatically load whenever I enter the Address page instead of clicking the icon to load it?

Comment: Put the code in a function and call the function where you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Input Controller or more specifically a TextEditingController https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

This way you can detect when the user enters text in the field or when the user leaves the filed to go to the next etc. You have to decide what should trigger the map.

```
// create a text field controller
final myController = TextEditingController();
...

// add controller to text field
TextField(
  controller: myController,
),
...

// add a listener to the controller
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // Start listening to changes.
  myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
}

// function called every time the text field is changed
void _printLatestValue() {
  print('Second text field: ${myController.text}');
  // HERE YOU CAN CALL THE MAP
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

      await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Map(
                    latitude: latitude == null
                        ? position.latitude
                        : double.parse(latitude),
                    longitude: longitude == null
                        ? position.longitude
                        : double.parse(longitude),
                    from: getTranslated(context, 'ADDADDRESS'),
                  )));
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
      List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          double.parse(latitude), double.parse(longitude));

      state = placemark[0].administrativeArea;
      country = placemark[0].country;
      pincode = placemark[0].postalCode;
      //  address = placemark[0].name;
      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          countryC.text = country;
          stateC.text = state;
          pincodeC.text = pincode;
          // addressC.text = address;
        });
}
```